# How can I use list_stacks in boto3 to find a stack and filter it?

Tags: boto3, boto

How can I use list_stacks in boto3 to find a stack called test-logging-9823492834, the number being random?

My attempt:

```
for stack in qa.cfn.list_stacks().filter(Prefix='test-logging'):
  print('{0}:{1}'.format(stack.name, stack.key))

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'filter'
```

Answer (score 0):

In boto3, the `list_stacks()` function does not have a filter method for `stack_names`.

The client only has 2 options,
in which you can only filter the output on the basis of `StackStatus`:

`response = client.list_stacks(NextToken='string',StackStatusFilter='option')`

The response from above call will only return a dict of `StackSummaries`:

```
{
    'StackSummaries': [
        {
            'StackId': 'string',
            'StackName': 'string',
            'TemplateDescription': 'string',
            'CreationTime': datetime(2015, 1, 1),
            'LastUpdatedTime': datetime(2015, 1, 1),
            'DeletionTime': datetime(2015, 1, 1),
            'StackStatus': 'CREATE_IN_PROGRESS'|'CREATE_FAILED'|'CREATE_COMPLETE'|'ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS'|'ROLLBACK_FAILED'|'ROLLBACK_COMPLETE'|'DELETE_IN_PROGRESS'|'DELETE_FAILED'|'DELETE_COMPLETE'|'UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS'|'UPDATE_COMPLETE_CLEANUP_IN_PROGRESS'|'UPDATE_COMPLETE'|'UPDATE_ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS'|'UPDATE_ROLLBACK_FAILED'|'UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE_CLEANUP_IN_PROGRESS'|'UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE'|'REVIEW_IN_PROGRESS',
            'StackStatusReason': 'string',
            'ParentId': 'string',
            'RootId': 'string',
            'DriftInformation': {
                'StackDriftStatus': 'DRIFTED'|'IN_SYNC'|'UNKNOWN'|'NOT_CHECKED',
                'LastCheckTimestamp': datetime(2015, 1, 1)
            }
        },
    ],
    'NextToken': 'string'
}
```

So, for your use case you will need to loop + filter the `response['StackSummaries']` dict yourself in python rather than looking for an option with boto3.

**EDIT**
The option that can be used perfectly here is `describe_stacks` which will return info about a particular stack.
  [look here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudformation.html#CloudFormation.Client.describe_stacks)

Hope this clarifies.